# Why is the gate called "Raven's gate"?

Tags: the-gatekeepers

In the *The Gatekeepers* series by Anthony Horowitz, the first gate that could possibly release the Old Ones that Matthew Freeman has to deal with is named "Raven's Gate", in Lesser Malling.

On a reread, I can't figure out *why* it's named "Raven's Gate". What does it have to do with ravens? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in the novel. This is the gate that beyond which be ravens (e.g. death and disaster).

> *“I said it was destroyed because the people thought it was evil,” the
>   professor corrected him. “They were mistaken. **They gave it a name,
>   Raven’s Gate, because the raven has always been associated with death.**
>   They had a memory that connected the stones with something horrible…
>   But after all the years that had passed, they had forgotten what it
>   was. And in the end they came to think that it was the stones
>   themselves that were evil. So they tore them down.”*